# What is the probability that these two segments don't meet?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinations

Twelve points are evenly spaced around a circle. Anna randomly chooses two of these and then  Billy does the same. Anna then draws a line segment connecting her two points and then Billy does the same. What is the probability that their line segments will not meet?

My Attempt:

Label each point from $1$ to $12$ as on a clockface. Anna can choose her pair of numbers in $\binom{12}{2}$ ways and likewise for Billy. Therefore the total number of ways that Anna and Billy can choose their respective pairs is $\binom{12}{2}^2$.

We will now assume that Anna picks the number $12$ and then multiply out final answer by $12$. If she picks $12$ and $1$ then, for the segments to not meet, Billy must pick his two numbers from the set $\{2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11\}$. This can be done in $\binom{10}{2}$ ways. If she picks $12$ and $2$ then, for the segments to not meet, Billy must pick his two numbers from the set $\{3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11\}$. This can be done in $\binom{9}{2}$ ways. If she picks $12$ and $3$ then, for the segments to not meet, Billy must pick his two numbers from either of the sets $\{4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11\}$ or $\{1,2\}$. This can be done in $\binom{8}{2}+\binom{2}{2}$ ways. Continuing this way, we find the the total number of ways that their numbers will not meet is 
$$12\times\sum_{i=0}^{10}\left(\binom{i}{2}+\binom{10-i}{2}\right).$$
It follows that the probability that their lines will not meet is
$$\frac{12\times\sum_{i=0}^{10}\left(\binom{i}{2}+\binom{10-i}{2}\right)}{\binom{12}{2}^2}=\frac{10}{11}.$$
This answer seems higher than expected, but I can't find my mistake. Might someone spot a flaw in my reasoning?

Comment: The error is multiplying by $12$. You are duplicating pairs.

Comment: If line segments have a common extremity,  you count them as intersecting segments, isn't it ?

Comment: @quasi Indeed. Anna's choice of (12,1) is also included again as (1,12). Either divide by 2 afterwards, or equivalently, take 6 instead of 12.

Comment: Yes quasi and Nick Pavlov. I see it now.

Comment: @Auslander: Also, in your work (and by the way +1), for the final result, didn't you mean "the probability that the lines will **not** meet is ..."?

Comment: Yes. I've added the word. I think I do not deserve a +1, especially when I see your very cool solution.

Comment: No, your work (with the easy correction) is fine as an alternative way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an alternate approach . . .

For the chords to not meet, a necessary condition is that together, Anna and Billy choose $4$ distinct points. The number of subsets of $4$ points is ${\large{\binom{12}{4}}}$.

Once the $4$ points are chosen, Anna must choose two adjacent points (in the circular order), so there are $4$ possible choices. Once Anna's choice is made, Billy's choice is forced.

Hence, the probability that the chords don't meet is 
$${\large{\frac{4\binom{12}{4}}{\binom{12}{2}^2}}}=\frac{5}{11}$$

Comment: +1 right answer neatly found. But the OP asked where s/he went wrong.

Comment: I identified the error in my first comment.

Comment: Yes you did sorry.

Comment: Neat. And by comparing the two answers I guess you've come up with a way of enumerating the triangular numbers.